# Authentication after registering user necessary?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I'm currently trying to understand authentication in passport. (On a sidenote, I'm also using passport-local-mongoose.)

My question is:

If I post to my login route, I'm currently doing the following:

```
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
User.register(new User(req.body.user), req.body.password, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
        // Do something
    }

    req.login(user, function (err) {
        // Do simething
    });
});
```

That work's fine so far and after the login my user is authenticated. However, I often see in other implementations that programmers either use `passport.authentiacte(..)` before the login or only use `passport.authentiacte(..)` in the registration-route. But do I actually have to run `passport.authentiacte(..)` as I registered my user the event before or is this optional? Are there any security vulnerabilities if I don't use `passport.authentiacte(..)` during my registration process?

Thank you!

Comment: I can't see vulnerabilities in trusting credentials that the new user has just filled in (except if user id is not unique in your db).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go directly to the home page without loging in then you have to authenticate after user.register otherwise authentication after login is enough